# Javascript to jQuery? (Iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following javascript to replace the contents of an iframe:

```
// find existing iframe
var original = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

// create new iframe
var newFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
newFrame.src = '/confirmation/show/' + this.value;
newFrame.className = 'field w45 right';
newFrame.id='confirmation_preview';
newFrame.title="Confirmation_Preview";

// find out where it goes
var parent = original.parentNode;

// replace the old with the new
parent.replaceChild(newFrame, original);
```

I do it this way because if I just change the iframe `src`, the browser adds an entry into the history, so if a user wants to go back a page, they would have to step back through all the iframe re-loads. With this method, they won't have that problem.

**My question is this: how can I achieve the same result in jQuery?**

Comment: Why would you want to? It can't possibly be any faster.

Comment: You can use native JavaScript alongside jQuery, why not keep this code if it works? Are you looking for something specific like speed increase?

Comment: `->` http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: Because all other javascript in this project is in jQuery, so just for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use jquery to make more concise code, but really think what you have is good enough solution performance wise:

```
// find existing iframe
var original = $("iframe").get(0);

// create new iframe
var newFrame = $("<iframe src='/confirmation/show/'" + this.value + "' class='field w45 right' id='confirmation_preview' title='Confirmation_Preview'></iframe>").get(0);

// replace the old with the new
original.parentNode.replaceChild(newFrame, original);
```

**Update:** Commenter suggested using replaceWith to make even more concise.  I've not tested this:

```
// replace the old with the new
 $("iframe").replaceWith("<iframe src='/confirmation/show/'" + this.value + "' class='field w45 right' id='confirmation_preview' title='Confirmation_Preview'></iframe>");
```

Comment: jQuery has http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/.

Comment: There is an error in the code due to an extra single quote after "show/" but other than that, this did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks something like this. I don't know what this is referring to in your src attribute so you will have to fill that in.

```
var original = $('iframe');

var newFrame = $('iframe').attr('src','/confirmation/show' + 'INSERT WHAT THAT IS HERE').addClass('field w45 right').attr('id', 'confirmation_preview').attr('title', 'Confirmation_Preview');  
var parent = original.parent();

newFrame.appendTo(parent);
original.remove();
```

All I did was take your stuff and put it in the exact same way as you would in jQuery.  I did not try and make it more concise.  But jQuery is javascript so why not leave it as it is.

Comment: You'd also have to remove the existing iframe.